# issue with text(function(index, oldText)) in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
        $("p").text(function(index, oldText) {
                return "Existing text: " + oldText + ". New text: A dynamically set text (#" + index + ")";
        });
});
</script>
```

Result:

```
Existing text: Paragraph 1. New text: A dynamically set text (#0)

Existing text: Paragraph 2. New text: A dynamically set text (#1)

Existing text: Paragraph 3. New text: A dynamically set text (#2)
```

Question:

If I only want to apply it to Paragraph 1 and Paragraph 2(below is the result I want), how could I do?

```
Existing text: Paragraph 1. New text: A dynamically set text (#0)

Existing text: Paragraph 2. New text: A dynamically set text (#1)

Paragraph 3.
```

Comment: Hmm.. can we make use of index here? Yes! `if (index < 2)` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[:lt(index)](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** selector to fetch the elements less that a particular index (0 indexed so 2 here for specifying less that 3rd element).

```
$("p:lt(2)").text(function(index, oldText) {
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NVVcq/)**